# getpaid version conflict

Tags: plone

installing getpaid for plone, several distributions complained that

We already have: egg.name 0.0 
but another.egg 1.2.3 requires 'egg.name>=4.5.6'

I have managed to move forward by pinning the requested versions until:

```
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zope.component 3.5.1
but zope.site 3.9.2 requires 'zope.component>=3.8.0'.
but zope.browserresource 3.12.0 requires 'zope.component>=3.8.0'.
```

pinning zope.component to 3.8.0 gives the following:

```
Error: There is a version conflict.
We already have: zope.component 3.8.0
but five.localsitemanager 1.3 requires 'zope.component<3.6dev'.
```

How can I circumvent this (catch 22)?

My buildout: http://www.pastie.org/3050771

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a KGS (known good set) in your buildout:

- http://good-py.appspot.com/release/getpaid/0.10.4

e.g.

```
[buildout]
extends = http://good-py.appspot.com/release/getpaid/0.10.4
versions = versions
```

Comment: would this extend replace 
extends = versions.cfg?

Comment: merging the contents of my buidout with the contents of this kgs still produces: We already have: zope.location 0.0
but zope.intid 3.7.2 requires 'zope.location>=3.5.4'.
http://www.pastie.org/3055193

Comment: Use a KGS and only a KGS. In other words, don't merge buildouts. Use a buildout with only that KGS until you are able to complete a successful run. Or, paste the output of bin/buildout -vvvv if you like.

Comment: The versions from the KGS you linked still have a conflict: "We already have: zope.location 0.0 but zope.intid 3.7.2 requires 'zope.location>=3.5.4'."

Comment: My final solution was to start from scratch with a unified install and this KGS and add my other products/database to it.

Answer (score 4):

In general, what is advisable in such a case is to take it step by step.  The trick is to add this line to your [buildout] section:

```
allow-picked-versions = false
```

This tells zc.buildout to immediately quit when it sees that a package is required that is not pinned.  Then you can go to http://pypi.python.org and search for that package and see if you can figure out which version fits best with your other packages and especially your Plone version.  On Plone 3 when a zope.* package is not pinned, best is usually to pin it to the oldest version you can find.

In this specific case, those zope.site and zope.browserresource versions are quite recent and require a too new zope.component version.

This is untested, but these pins *might* work (no guarantees):

```
zope.site = 3.5.1
zope.component = 3.5.1
zope.browserresource = 3.9.0
```

Comment: allow-picked-versions shows: While:
  Installing.
  Loading extensions.
  Getting distribution for 'buildout.dumppickedversions'.
Error: Picked: buildout.dumppickedversions = 0.4

Comment: That is perfect.  Now you add 'buildout.dumppickedversions = 0.4' to your versions list and run bin/buildout again and fix the next errors in the same way.  Only: for each package that is printed with this error you should take a moment to figure out if the picked version (always the latest) will really work with the rest of the buildout.

Comment: zope.authentication 3.7.0 (lowest version) requires 'zope.component>=3.6.0'. five.localsitemanager 1.3 requires zope.component<3.6.  Upgrading five.localsitemanager to 2 then prompts for a higher version of zope2, and whenever I change that, I get errors...  http://www.pastie.org/3152711